# Byobu Shift + F2 not working on windows

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-16.04, byobu

Connecting to byobu in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a Windows 10 system, when I type Shift+F2 to get a vertical split, nothing happens. Typing plain F2 works and opens a new window. Ctrl + F2 works too and splits vertically.

I tried all the terminal keyboard types in PuTTY/Kitty/ConEmu configuration (ex. XTerm R2, Linux) without any luck. Any ideas? Is there any another keyboard shortcut to do the same thing?

Answer (score 5):

How about using the Ctrl + A commands which is what I use mostly.

Ctrl + A then | will give you a horizontal split 
Ctrl + A then % will give you a vertical split